# Hide description for specific category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, product-list

need to hide **description** on specific **parent category** and all child category.

like

- test = parent
- abc1 = child category
- abc2
- abc3 and more 70+

i want hide description on test category and all sub category on list page.

Comment: What you have tried ? add your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit clunky but you can do this fairly easily using css.

In the front-end html you should have a categorypath-x class on the body element which you can target with attribute selectors to display:none the description for only the parent category and its children.

If this interests you but you don't know how to go about it I can post an example.

Comment: using coding not css.